# Java - JPanel can't draw background image

Tags: java, jpanel

I am learning how to work with Gui's in java. Currently I'm trying to make a simple program that opens a Gui and draws an image to the background. The problem is that the background is completely white instead of the image.

**Code:**

**Main.java:**

```
package com.flaghacker.buckygame;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GuiFrame guiFrame = new GuiFrame();
    }
}
```

**GuiFrame.java:**

```
package com.flaghacker.buckygame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GuiFrame extends JFrame
{
    private GuiPanel guiPanel;

    public GuiFrame()
    {
        //General
        super("Title");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Size
        this.setSize(1100, 650);
        this.setResizable(true);

        //Components
        guiPanel = new GuiPanel();
        this.add(guiPanel);

        //Final
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**GuiPane.java:**

```
package com.flaghacker.buckygame;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class GuiPanel extends JPanel
{
    private Image backGround;

    public GuiPanel()
    {
        backGround = new ImageIcon("D:\\Install\\Java Projects\\Testing\\Bucky\\Back.jpg").getImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code and it works ... the possible problem are two

first) your image isn't in

`"D:\\Install\\Java Projects\\Testing\\Bucky\\Back.jpg"`

i suggested you to use

`"D:/Install/Java Projects/Testing/Bucky/Back.jpg"`

and verify
Case insensitive.

second) the image Back.jpg have width and height more high of 1100 650 so you display only a top left angle of image

Comment: I checked very carefully, and the extension was .png instead of .jpg. Thanks!